# Fiori Standard app cross navigation to an App with Adaptation

Tags: sapui5, sap-fiori, sap-business-application-studio

I create an adaptation using SAP Business Application Studio for app `F1991`, create a tile to this adaptation and it works fine.

But when another app (e.g. `F1048`) navigates to app `F1991`, this navigation goes to the app without the adaptation.

How can I make the navigation from all other apps to `F1991` open with my custom adaptation?

Thanks

Comment: Create an adaptation for F1048 that navigates to to the adaptation.